# Play Music or Video during phone call like instagram in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, video

I am working on app in iOS. I have a requirement to play music on the phone and record video from the app. I have accomplished this with `AVAudioSession`.

This is code I used in `AppDelegate's didfinishlaunching options`:

```
AVAudioSession *session1 = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance]; 
[session1 setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];
[session1 setActive:YES error:nil]; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

But now I am stuck trying to play video or music during phone calls like in instagram app it works in iPhone. Issue is when I got a call and am on my app and video is playing before call, when I return to my app, the video player stuck.

Comment: Did you solved this buddy? We are atuck also.. :/